# How to assign max id value of table to a variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need the max id of a table and want to access this value to insert into another table, but I am not able to access it outside the callback function. How can I access this value outside the block?

I am using Sequelize and Node.js. My code is:

```
var employeeCode = 'EMP1';

var employeeCodeObj = Employee.max('id').then(function(max) {
  var maxid = max + 1;
  employeeCode = "EMP" + maxid;
  console.log(employeeCode);
}).catch(err => {
  res.send({
    msg: 'Unable to generate employee code!',
    status: 'Failure',
    response: 500,
    data: []
  });
});
console.log(employeeCode);
```

The table has one row but when I print this value, it always prints `EMP1` when the result should be `EMP2`.

Comment: Are you sure your execution flow is not going into catch part of your code ?

Comment: yes when i am print max value in then() block it print 2, and in outer it print 1.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is asynchronous.

This means that the last console.log will execute first than the function in then.

The code in the max function will execute and the remaining code will carry on. Only when the max is calculated the then function will execute but meanwhile the console.log was already executed.

You will need to execute the code that needs the max employee inside the then function or use a module like "async" to help working with asynchronous code and  resolve the callback hell.

Check this website: http://callbackhell.com/.

Comment: yes, correct ..the outer console is execute first then max query is execute. i am confuse about promise, defferd & q. can you please tell which is the latest liberary to use for asynchronous code.

Comment: I've been using "async" (http://caolan.github.io/async/). Is very simple to understand and use.